# Classes: Alternative way of adding len()

Tags: python, string, operator-overloading

I am building a string Class that behaves like a regular string class except that the addition operator returns the sum of the lengths of the two strings instead of concatenating them. And then a multiplication operator returns the products of the length of the two strings. So I was planning on doing

```
   class myStr(string):
         def __add__(self):
             return len(string) + len (input)
```

at least that is what I have for the first part but that is apparently not correct. Can someone help me correct it.

Comment: Please always post the full error which your code gives you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? That's a very odd design. An object that _has_ a string, and uses it in various ways, and even delegates some methods straight through to the string… that's not too bad. But an object that _is a_ string, and yet does some of the operations in non-string-like ways, is just going to be confusing.

Comment: Also, note that, once you get this right, `myStr('abc') + 'def'` will be 6, but `'abc' + myStr('def')` will be `'abcdef'`. And, worse, `s = myStr('abc'); s += myStr('def')` will set `s` to 6. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @abarnert This is homework. Same user has other homework questions of similar type.

Comment: ...as you should know, having just answered such a question.

Comment: @Marcin: I'm beginning to suspect that she needs a better professor (or tutorial or whatever). Anyone who would give this assignment is either deliberately trying to confuse his students, or confused as a result of too much LDS^H^H^HLOOPS in the 60s…

Comment: You mean LSD. LDS is the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, and they're not big fans of mind-altering substances. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to derive from `str`, and you can use `len(self)` to get the length of the current instance. You also need to give `__add__` a parameter for the other operand of the `+` operator.

```
class myStr(str):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return len(self) + len(other)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class myStr(str):
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         return len(self) + len(other)
... 
>>> foo = myStr('foo')
>>> foo
'foo'
>>> foo + 'bar'
6
```

Comment: You don't need `str.__len__(self)` or `super`; `len(self)` works just fine. (He hasn't overridden `__len__`, so `myStr.__len__` is the exact same method as `str.__len__`.)

Answer (score 1):

`string` is not a class. It's not anything*. There is no context where `len(string)` will work  unless you define `string`.

Secondly, `__add__` does not have an `input` parameter.

You need to fix both of these issues.

`*` You could import a module called `string`, but it's not something that just exists in global scope.

Comment: `string` is [a module in the stdlib](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).